# Win 7/Linux Dual Boot Hibernation Issue

Tags: windows-7, linux, hibernate

Win7 on SSD, Linux on HDD, Grub on HDD.
-for the first 1-2 times I could normally hibernate my win7, and boot into linux but idk what - somewhat has changed. Now if I try to hibernate, my screen turns off for a while(15 sec) and turns on with the login screen (just like if I pressed win+L)

Answer (score 0):

It's actually turns in to Lock mode instead of Hibernate mode.

I have exactly the same system configuration with you and also encountered this problem. 
There are some solutions to solve the issue in Microsoft forum. One of it is to mark the Windows Reserved Partition as active using disk management or diskpart utility. Although many users find it useful, it doesn't helps in my PC.

```
1. DiskPart:
```

open cmd

type diskpart

select disk 0

select partition 1

active

exit

```
2 Disk Management:
```

Open Star menu

right click on Computer and click manage

Find Disk Management utility under Storage

right click on the 100MB partition and mark it as active.

I hope it solves your problem while I am still desperately waiting for a working solution...

Comment: Hi! Finally I figured out how it works and I am able to find a workaround. YOU HAVE TO GRANT THE WINDOWS DISK WITH HIGHER PRIORITY OVER THE UBUNTU DISK IN BIOS-Startup. I installed Windows 7 to SSD and Ubuntu to HDD, via Grub on HDD to dual boot. However, I set the Startup order in BIOS to HDD>SSD. After switching back the default BIOS startup setting, Hibernate in windows and Ubuntu works flawlessly, though I have to access BIOS every time... Hibernate checks access to Windows Boot Manager for system resuming, whereas my BIOS setting bypassed WinBootMan at startup and caused its malfunction.